In this "alphametic rebus", what number is TWO?
Two times two:
Each letter in the "alphametic rebus" shown in the figure stands for some digit; different letters denote different digits, dots denote arbitrary digits. What number is TWO?

   TWO
  xTWO
------
  ...O
  ..W
...T
------
......

Clarification:  Assume there are no leading zeros.
Attribution: A. Shvetsov

Let's start with O:

 The only digits whose squares end in the same digit are 0, 1, 5, and 6. We can immediately rule out 0 and 1 as TWO x O is four digits long. We can also rule out 5, as products of numbers ending in 5 must end with 5 or 0, meaning T, W, and O would all have to be 5 or 0, a contradiction. Therefore, O is 6.

We know that

 6 has the property that multiplying it by any even digit yields a number ending in that digit. Thus, T and W must both be even, and they obviously can't be 0 either. That leaves 2, 4, and 8 as possible options. We know W yields a smaller product than T or O, so it must be 2 or 4 and T must be 4 or 8.

However,

 TWO x W must only be three digits long, which means T x W must not exceed 10. If T is 8, any non-identity multiple of TWO will be greater than 1000; therefore, T must be 4 and W must be 2.

Let's check our work:

 
    426
   x426
 ------
   2556
   852
 1704
 ------
 181476

That checks out, so TWO is

 426

